# How to integrate an external application in iframe

Tags: asp.net, iframe

I'm working on a project and I want to integrate an application called `what'sup gold`. Here is my code below:

```
<iframe height="300px" width="100%" src="http://localhost/NmConsole/#discover/p=%7B%22fullScreen%22%3Atrue%7D">
app1
</iframe>
```

the problem is when running the code I got these errors:

> Refused to display 'http://localhost/NmConsole/#discover/p=%7B%22fullScreen%22%3Atrue%7D' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.
>   And
>   Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE

Can anyone explain what the problem is exactly and how to go about resolving it?

Comment: Do you control the "what'sup gold" application?

Comment: no i'm just a normal user for the application

Comment: Well, then the error message seems straight forward. Did you research at all what the purpose of `X-Frame-Options` is?

Comment: yes, and most of them are saying that i have to have a full control of the application. but i was wondering if there is another way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE means the resource (the app that you are trying to get) is not allowed to run under another domain. So unless you have full control over the domain in which the original app runs, there's no way to display it under your own domain.